# How to stop input value from overwriting table data in Blazor app?

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I have a table that pulls its data from a SQLite DB and allows for editing in app by switching that row to a series on input fields.

I want to add the ability to cancel, and currently when hitting the cancel button the table is updated with the edited value from the input field. After a page reload it shows it was not committed to the database and all my other DB functions work as intended. How do I stop the table from being updated with the input value?

Here is an shortened version of what my razor page looks like.

```
@code
{
  public List<Item>? itemArr;
  public Item? ToUpdateItem;
  public int EditId;

  public void ShowEdit()
  {
    edit = true;
  }

  public void CancelEdit()
  {
    edit = false;
    editId = -1;
  }

  // Other DB functions
}

// Other Page markup and page flow control

<table>
  @foreach (var item in itemArr)
  {
    if (!edit)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@item.Title</td>
        <td>@item.Description</td>
        <td><button name="edit" type="submit" @onclick="() => ShowEdit()">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    }
    else
    {
      <tr>
        <td><input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" @bind="@ToUpdateItem.Title"></td>
        <td><input id="Description" name="Description" type="text" @bind="@ToUpdateItem.Description"></td>

        <td><button name="save" type="submit" @onclick="() => SaveEdit()">Save</button></td>
        <td><button name="cancel" type="reset" @onclick="() => CancelEdit()">Cancel</button></td>
      </tr>
    }
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Your cancel button should not be of type "submit".

Comment: There might be other problems as well.  Hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Is this Blazor Server or Blazor Webassembly?

Comment: Its is a Blazor Server app

Comment: @RobertHarvey There really isn't any other code that interacts to the problem I'm having. I provided as much as I could without bloating the post. Changing the button type="reset" did not resolve the issue

Comment: @RobertHarvey plus it shouldn't matter what the button type is as the input fields are not tied to a form tag

Comment: There's something wrong in the methods you've hooked.

Comment: You are describing a successful 2-way bind of your `item` objects with your input elements , which you've achieved with `@bind`, and which is working as expected.

Comment: How is the item you want to edit being assigned to `ToUpdateItem`? If you are simply assigning a reference then you will get the behavior you're describing. There's a couple ways to support the ability to undo: 1) make a copy of the item being edited, update that copy, and then apply the changes to the original when saving; 2) make a copy of the item, update the original, apply the copy back to the original if changes are cancelled. Otherwise you are just working on the same referenced object the whole time and there's no way to undo anything.